# Data Transformations in R

Tags: r

I have a need to look at the data in a data frame in a different way.  Here is the problem..

I have a data frame as follows

```
Person  Item  BuyOrSell
1        a    B
1        b    S
1        a    S
2        d    B
3        a    S
3        e    S
```

I need it be transformed into this way. Show the sum of all transactions made by the Person on individual items.

```
Person   a   b    d   e
1        2   1    0   0
2        0   0    1   0
3        1   0    0   1
```

I was able to achieve the above by using the

`table(Person,Item)`  in R

The new requirement I have is to see the data as follows. Show the sum of all transactions made by the Person on individual items broken by the transaction type (B or S)

```
Person    aB   aS   bB   bS   dB   dS   eB   eS
1          1    1    0    1    0    0   0     0
2          0    0    0    0    1    0   0     0
3          1    0    0    0    0    0   0     1
```

So i created a new column and appended the values of both the Item and BuyOrSell.

```
df$newcol<-paste(Item,"-",BuyOrSell,sep="")
table(Person,newcol)
```

and was able to achieve the above results.

Is there a better way in R to do this type of transformation ?

Comment: The `paste` method is fine. You can obtain the same information (though not in the same format) with `as.data.frame(table(Person, Item, BuyOrSell))`, but I don't know that this method is any better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way (creating a new column via `paste`) is probably the easiest. You could also do this:

```
require(reshape2)
dcast(Person~Item+BuyOrSell,data=df,fun.aggregate=length,drop=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks guys.  I added an additional requirement, please suggest the needful.

Comment: By convention, users do not tack on follow-on questions to a single question. You instead ask it as a separate question

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up ... i will post a different question.