# R Data Transformations

Tags: r

I have a need to look at the data in a data frame in a different way.  Here is the problem..

I have a data frame as follows

```
Person  Item  BuyOrSell
1        a    B
1        b    S
1        a    S
2        d    B
3        a    S
3        e    S
```

One of the requirements I have is to see the data as follows. Show the sum of all transactions made by the Person on individual items broken by the transaction type (B or S)

```
Person    aB   aS   bB   bS   dB   dS   eB   eS
1          1    1    0    1    0    0   0     0
2          0    0    0    0    1    0   0     0
3          1    0    0    0    0    0   0     1
```

So i created a new column and appended the values of both the Item and BuyOrSell.

```
df$newcol<-paste(Item,"-",BuyOrSell,sep="")
table(Person,newcol)
```

and was able to achieve the above results.

The last transformation requirement which was a tough nut to crack was as follows....

```
  aB   aS   bB   bS   dB   dS   eB   eS
aB 1    1    0    1    0   0     0   0
aS 1    2    0    1    0   0     0   1
bB 0    0    0    0    0   0     0   0
bS 1    1    0    0    0   0     0   0
dB 0    0    0    0    1   0     0   0
dS 0    0    0    0    0   0     0   0
eB 0    0    0    0    0   0     0   0
eS 0    1    0    0    0   0     0   1
```

where the above table had to be filled in with the number of people who made a particular transaction also made a transaction on another item.

I tried `table(newcol,newcol)` but it generated counts only for aB-aB,aS-aS,bB-bB,..... and 0s for all other combinations.

Any ideas on what package or command will let me crack this nut ?

Comment: I think you should accept the answer to your previous question first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417698/data-transformations-in-r

Comment: just did. Thanks Arun !

Comment: could you explain your criteria to get the final table a bit more detailed please? I'm having a hard time understanding "where the above table had to be... on another item"

Comment: Arun, the table shows the counts of all people who bought one particular item from the row also bought an item form the column. For example, if user A bought Item A and Item B, then a_B*b_B =1, if user B also bought the same combination of items, then a_B*b_B should be incremented by 1 and the result would be a_B*b_B=2

Comment: and if the same user bought the same combination of items twice, i will still add it to the count.

Comment: I think it just requires a matrix multiplication from `df2`. Check my answer to see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't the final result just:

```
# Following Ricardo's solution for casting, but using `acast` instead
A <- acast(Person~Item+BuyOrSell,data=df,fun.aggregate=length,drop=FALSE)

# A' * A
> t(A) %*% A
#     a_B a_S b_B b_S d_B d_S e_B e_S
# a_B   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
# a_S   1   2   0   1   0   0   0   1
# b_B   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# b_S   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
# d_B   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
# d_S   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# e_B   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
# e_S   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a better way, but here's a method using the package `reshape2`.

```
require(reshape2)
#reshapes data so each item and buy/sell event interaction occurs once
df2 <- dcast(Person~Item+BuyOrSell,data=df,fun.aggregate=length,drop=FALSE)
df2
  # Person a_B a_S b_B b_S d_B d_S e_B e_S
# 1      1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
# 2      2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
# 3      3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1

#reshapes data so every row is an interaction by person
df3 <- melt(df2,id.vars="Person")
head(df3)
     # Person variable value
# 1       1      a_B     1
# 2       2      a_B     0
# 3       3      a_B     0
# 4       1      a_S     1
# 5       2      a_S     0
# 6       3      a_S     1

#removes empty rows where no action occurred
#removes value column
df4 <- with(df3,
  data.frame(Person=rep.int(Person,value),variable=rep.int(variable,value))
#performs a self-merge: now each row is 
#every combination of two actions that one person has done
df5 <- merge(df4,df4,by="Person")
head(df5)
  # Person variable.x variable.y
# 1      1        a_B        a_B
# 2      1        a_B        a_S
# 3      1        a_B        b_S
# 4      1        a_S        a_B
# 5      1        a_S        a_S
# 6      1        a_S        b_S

#tabulates variable interactions
with(df5,table(variable.x,variable.y))
```

Comment: could you please explain your solution ? especially the df4

Comment: I changed `df4` originally because I thought you would count person 1 twice if they bought item A twice, but on re-reading the question I think you just want number of people. I've changed it back now.

Comment: your initial solution was perfect. i would count person 1 twice. i have posted my answer below..i am stumped with what i am doing differently based on your solution. Please comment on my post below.

Answer (score 0):

Blue Magister,your solution works perfectly and i analyzed each an every step that you performed.

The output of df4 was follows:

```
 Person variable
1      1      a_B
2      1      a_S
3      3      a_S
4      1      b_S
5      2      d_B
6      3      e_S
```

The output of `with(df5,table(variable.x,variable.y))`  was

```
variable.y
variable.x a_B a_S b_B b_S d_B d_S e_B e_S
       a_B   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
       a_S   1   2   0   1   0   0   0   1
       b_B   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       b_S   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
       d_B   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
       d_S   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       e_B   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
       e_S   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

which is exactly what i want.

When i look at the output of d4 it was almost similar to the my newcol solution ( using paste )

```
> df
  Person newcol
1      1    a-B
2      1    b-S
3      1    a-S
4      2    d-B
5      3    a-S
6      3    e-S
```

The only difference here is the ordering of the rows when compared to your df4.

So, i ended up running this command

```
dfx <- merge(df,df,by="Person")
 with(dfx,table(newcol.x,newcol.y))
```

and it generated the following...

```
    newcol.y
newcol.x a-B a-S b-S d-B e-S
     a-B   1   1   1   0   0
     a-S   1   2   1   0   1
     b-S   1   1   1   0   0
     d-B   0   0   0   1   0
     e-S   0   1   0   0   1
```

The above output ignored few rows and columns. What am i doing different from you ?

Comment: You should move this text to a separate question instead of asking through an 'answer'. Link back to your previous questions as well so people understand what you're asking.

Comment: Essentially the difference stems from `levels(df4$variable)` and your `levels(df$newcol)`.